# TypeScript, Angular how to convert attribute of an object in list to string separeted comma

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have an array of person objects that I displayed in HTML using ngFor Angular 5.

```
persons:Array<Person>=[];
```

the Person objects contains an Array of Role object described as below:

```
export class Role{
    id:string
    label:string;   
}

export class Person{
   // many attributes
   roles:Array<Person>;

}
```

In the HTML i am using ngFor to fetch the persons Array in div tag. and I want to get string separated comma of the roles's label for each person and display it in div.

I want something like that:

```
<div *ngFor='let person of persons'>
   <p> {{ person.roles.label.join(',') }} </p>
</div>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `join` on the roles in the markup

```
<div *ngFor='let person of persons'>
   <p> {{ person.roles.join(',') }} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my issue, but this not what I mean roles contains label and id. An i want string separated comma of label attribute @Suren Srapyan

Comment: @Suren_Srapyan  I mean roles contains label and id. An i want string separated comma of label attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can map your roles to role names first and then join them together.

```
<div *ngFor='let person of persons'>
    <p> {{ person.roles.map(role => role.label).join(',') }} </p>
</div>
```

If roles can be undefined or null you should also guard against that case.

```
<div *ngFor='let person of persons'>
    <p> {{ (person.roles || []).map(role => role.label).join(',') }} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I am not entirely sure this will work, as this is using arrow function (the `role => role.label` part) and I am not sure if this is supported in angular template expression syntax. If this does not work you might have to transform your data in your component or create a custom pipe in order to do the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

This code relves my probelm:

```
 <div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let role of person.roles"> 
        {{role.label}} + ","
    </ng-container>
 </div>
```